# Regex one-two digits in order in r

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to merge the files in R, using the pattern of file names from 1 to 14 using:

```
files = list.files(pattern = paste0(i, "_[0-9]+.out"))
DF <-  read.table(files[1], h = T)
for (f in files[-1]) DF <- rbind(DF, read.table(f, h = T))
```

It merges the files in order from 11-14 to 1-9, I would need from 1 to 14. any idea how to make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used `mixedsort()` from the gtools package.

```
library(gtools)
files <- mixedsort(list.files(pattern = paste0(i, "_[0-9]+.out")))
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, read.table, header = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to extract the numbers from the filename `order` them and reorder your `files`

```
files <- files[order(as.numeric(sub(".*_(\\d+).out", "\\1", files)))]
```

From here you can continue

```
DF <-  read.table(files[1], h = T)
for (f in files[-1]) DF <- rbind(DF, read.table(f, h = T))
```